# Cannot modify the font-size lower than 12px in larger screen?

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, angular8

I was trying to set a class for a `<p>` element. I set the font-size to be 9px through a .scss file in my Angular project.

It works perfectly fine in Google Chrome while I was using my 15" laptop. But when I switch to a larger screen (approx. 24") the font-size is locked to 12px. By 'locked', I mean changing the font-size from 1 to 12px won't change the size of the letters at all. Change it to 0 would make the words disappear while changing it to 13+ would enlarge their sizes. Strangely, the same style works fine in Firefox.

Could anyone explain why would that happen and how could I fix that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be Chrome, could be the OS, but either way there's a "minimum font size" setting. Anything less than 12pt (16px) is actually against WebAIM guidelines anyway.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The minimum font size for only certain window size? That's strange. I would search for that.